# How can I prevent my header layout from shifting on hover in Squarespace?

Tags: css, squarespace

I added some CSS to make header items bold on hover, but now it shifts the layout of those items to the left whenever you hover over one of them.
Here's the code that I'm using so far, any help is appreciated.

```
.header-nav-folder-item:hover a {
  font-weight: 550;
}

.header-nav-item--collection:hover a {
  font-weight: 550;
}

.header-nav-item--external:hover a {
  font-weight: 550;
}
```

[image]

Comment: if the font weight is the issue here then there's not much you can do. You can try a different effect on hover like adding bottom border or changing background.

Comment: you can define the width of each item in the header to constant width, so the bolding of one item won't affect the others

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/bold-on-hover-without-the-layout-shift/